# How to alias a function and call from function with original name

Tags: bash, zsh, command-not-found

This is more of an academic exercise but curious of the answer.
Here is the current code in question:

```
export original_command_not_found_handler="$(type -f command_not_found_handler)" # original func as string

function command_not_found_handler(){  # my custom override
  echo "my custom handler: $@"
  echo "
     ${original_command_not_found_handler}
      command_not_found_handler "$@"
  " | bash

}
```

what I am trying to do is override the original zsh function with my custom function and then call the original function from the override.

There are two problems with this code:

1. I am trying to call the original function from a subshell (piping to bash), but it would be best to call from the current shell not subshell.
2. it doesn't work since the original function is not being interpreted as desired in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `zsh`, functions and their definitions are exposed in the `$functions` special associative array, so to make a copy of a function, you just do:

```
functions[original_command_not_found_handler]=$functions[command_not_found_handler]
```

In `bash`, you can do:

```
eval "original_command_not_found_handle()
$(typeset -f command_not_found_handle | tail -n +2)"
```

(but beware that bash has had several bugs where `typeset -f` doesn't show the function definition properly in some corner cases; in theory, the same could happen with `zsh`'s `$functions`)

Then in both, you do:

```
command_not_found_handler() {
  echo my custom handler
  if was handled by my custom handler; then
    return "$some_ret_code"
  fi
  original_command_not_found_handler "$@"
}
```

(in bash, replace `handler` with `handle`)

Now, that means you can't do that more than once, or you'd need to choose a different name for the saved original handler one each time. Instead, you can embed the code of the original function inside your custom one as [I showed in the Q&A this is a follow-up on](/a/691427).